# .fillStyle not working, no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Rogue Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="canvasGame()">
  <canvas  id="myCanvas" width="800" height ="800">
    <p>Sorry your browser does not support canvas!</p>
  </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript:

```
function canvasGame() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  if(canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

The console out I get is:

file:///Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/Rogue/css/style.css
file:///Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/Rogue/js/main.js
GET 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js [HTTP/2.0 304 Not Modified 60ms]
file:///Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/Rogue/css/style.css

My canvas it not white its just the color that I set the body to in my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing 'var' in the script. You also don't have any objects to fill with the color. So you must create one in order to fill it with a color. See [this documentation on fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill) for more info. Here is an example that works:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Rogue Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="canvasGame()">
  <canvas  id="myCanvas" width="800" height ="800">
    <p>Sorry your browser does not support canvas!</p>
  </canvas>
<script>
function canvasGame() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  if(canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```